# Can I use gdb-heap on a core file?

Tags: c, gdb

I've a core file of a process (not running any more). I'd like to examine its heap. However the gdb-heap extension (https://fedorahosted.org/gdb-heap/) tries to open the  /proc/[pid]/maps file corresponding to the process when it was running... This obviously leads to an error and gdb-heap stops.

Is there a way to use or configure gdb-heap to circumvent this behavior ?
The project man page mentions gdb-heap should work with core files...

Thanks for any hint / help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use or configure gdb-heap to circumvent this behavior

It's obviously a bug in `gdb-heap`.

You should either fix it, or report it to `gdb-heap` developers (they probably never tried using it on a `core` file).

As far as I can tell, the problem exists in the very first git commit `c035ecc8` from 2010-07-26, which doesn't inspire confidence in this package.